# Como aplicar um style no html de um texto selecionado de um campo textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Olá, estou com uma duvida de como criar uma ação (botão) que ao clicar nele será aplicado inicialmente um style para um texto selecionado dentro de um campo textarea.

Sim é igual esses editores mesmo, onde você seleciona um pedaço do texto, paragrafo, etc.. e aplica uma cor de fundo ou cor de fonte mesmo.

Depois de umas pesquisa eu cheguei a um código assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 89</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doBold(){
            var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
            var editorHTML = editor.innerHTML;
            var selectionStart = 0, selectionEnd = 0;
            if (editor.selectionStart) selectionStart = editor.selectionStart;
            if (editor.selectionEnd) selectionEnd = editor.selectionEnd;
            if (selectionStart != selectionEnd) {
                var editorCharArray = editorHTML.split("");
                editorCharArray.splice(selectionEnd, 0, "</b>");
                editorCharArray.splice(selectionStart, 0, "<b>"); //must do End first
                editorHTML = editorCharArray.join("");
                editor.innerHTML = editorHTML;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="editor" cols="80" rows="20">This is some text to see what happens and when. You should be able to select some text in here then click the "Bold" button to make it bold.</textarea><br />
    <button onclick="doBold()">Bold</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém nesse código o que acontece é que ele aplica o    como se fosse apenas um texto mesmo, porém quero que ele aplique como se fosse por trás no html e claro dando o destaque no texto.

Até porque o conteúdo do html será salvo no banco.

Answer (score 1):

O elemento `textarea` é usado para texto, não para conteúdo `html`.

> The HTML  element represents a multi-line **plain-text**
> editing control, useful when you want to allow users to enter a
> sizeable amount of free-form text, for example a comment on a review
> or feedback form.

Da documentação aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Ou seja, o *plain-text* significa que apenas texto pode ser usado. O elemento pode ser estilizado, mas vai formatar todo o texto contido nele.

Para o que deseja fazer, deveria usar um elemento com `div` por exemplo, que suporta conteúdo `html`.